# In scala, check non nullity and apply method directly?

Tags: scala, if-statement, nullpointerexception, conditional-statements

With the following definitions:

```
class Test {
  var activated: Boolean = false
}

def maybeTest(): Test = {
  if(...) {
    val res = new Test
    if(...) res.activated = true
  } else null
}
```

I am having a lot of `if` structures like this one:

```
val myobject = maybeTest()
if(myobject != null && myobject.activated) {
  // Do something that does not care about the object
}
```

I would like to condensate it a little bit. Is there a nice way to define/write something like this to avoid a nullPointerException:

```
if(maybeTest() &&> (_.activated)) {
  ...
}
```

What is a best way of achieving this in scala?

Comment: Why not to use [scala.Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option)?

Comment: I love scala options, but I'm developping on Android so the less objects I create, the better.

Comment: In your example calling activated on maybeTest() can throw an NPE if maybeTest() will result in Null, so you firstly have to check what's the result of your maybeTest and then call activated

Comment: ok, I have rewritten my example to show what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best way with implicit classes, which properly handles the null case (although it might not be the most efficient way).

```
implicit class CheckNull[T](obj: T) {
  def call(f: T => Unit): Unit = if(obj != null) f(obj) else ()
  def is(f: T => Boolean): Boolean = if(obj != null) f(obj) else false
}
```

So I can write a type safe method and even calls:

```
if(maybeTest() is (_.activated)) {
  ...
}
myObjectMaybeNull call (_.pause())
```

Note that parenthesis around `(_.activated)` are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap such code in Option like this:

```
class Test(num: Int) {
  def someNum = num
}

val test: Test = null
Option(test).map(t => t.someNum)
```

In this example if your variable is null then you will get None, otherwise just work with Some(value)

**Update**

If you don't want to use Option, then you can define such function

```
class Test(num: Int) {
  def give = num
}

def ifDefAndTrue[T, K](obj: T)(ifTrue: T => Boolean)(then: => K) {
  if (obj != null && ifTrue(obj))
    then
}
```

In your case this look like this:

```
val test = new Test // assuming that activated is false

ifDefAndTrue(test)(_.activate) {
  println("results in unit")
}
```

But it contains side effect and not functional

Comment: Are you suggestion the following when using option:
if(Option(test).foldLeft(false){(a, b) => a || b.activated}) {
...
} ?

Comment: Option(foo).filter(_.activated).foreach { _ => ... }

Comment: Don't forget that every argument to a HOF such as `map`, `foreach`, `filter`, etc. (and `ifDefAndTrue`!) and all by-name parameters such as those to `getOrElse`, `getOrElseUpdate`, etc. require the generation of a separate class and instantiation of that class at every point of use. So `Option` may not be as (relatively) uneconomical of new instances as one might think at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for {m <- Option(maybeTest())
     if m.activated
    }
    {
        ... // do something with non-null, activated, m
    }
```